# Linux deb repo seems broken

Tags: visual-studio-code, repository, deb

Linux deb repo seems to contain some error:

This is what I get from apt update:

> Get:14 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64
>   Packages [156 kB] Err:14 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode
>   stable/main amd64 Packages   File has unexpected size (156354 !=
>   156065). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 13.74.252.37 80]   Hashes of
>   expected file:
>      - Filesize:156065 [weak]
>      - SHA512:12e6dffcd247d1ff067acfa61a3c4eb6078c326c2858feb4f6f141a1d809e22292a78282414a5c103038ea80bb63cd734c7516782c9809c341335083d4e7611b
>      - SHA256:c850f35f1979831ac75641978c397e51519fa22313598ec12bde5f52277044c0
>      - SHA1:1f65f4a7388c22bcf7b7f30fb7bc337c60d94b2e [weak]
>      - MD5Sum:4153a12e4a5629bfb14ed98f4c8ac234 [weak]   Release file created at: Thu, 12 Dec 2019 19:59:19 +0000 Reading package lists...
>   Done  E: Failed to fetch
>   http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2
>   File has unexpected size (156354 != 156065). Mirror sync in progress?
>   [IP: 13.74.252.37 80]    Hashes of expected file:
>       - Filesize:156065 [weak]
>       - SHA512:12e6dffcd247d1ff067acfa61a3c4eb6078c326c2858feb4f6f141a1d809e22292a78282414a5c103038ea80bb63cd734c7516782c9809c341335083d4e7611b
>       - SHA256:c850f35f1979831ac75641978c397e51519fa22313598ec12bde5f52277044c0
>       - SHA1:1f65f4a7388c22bcf7b7f30fb7bc337c60d94b2e [weak]
>       - MD5Sum:4153a12e4a5629bfb14ed98f4c8ac234 [weak]

The "https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2" real file size is: 156354
the file "https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease" tells that the size is 156065.

Furthermore:

```
gpg --verify Release.gpg Release

gpg: Signature made jue 12 dic 2019 20:59:31 CET

gpg:                using RSA key EB3E94ADBE1229CF

gpg: BAD signature from "Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>" [unknown]
```

Comment: Hi,
There's a reported issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/86858

Answer (score 4):

Try the following commands. first, remove all the vscode related files in source.list.d and then update your packages.

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list*
sudo apt-get update
```